# Proper way to provide spark application a parameter/arg with spaces in spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark

I have something like the following, a shell script with:

```
FOO="bar gum"
$ spark-submit --verbose --class SomeApp some.jar "$FOO"
```

However this would result in:

```
Main class:
SomeApp
Arguments:
bar
gum
```

Where as what I expected was a single argument of 'bar gum'

/update

So much for dumbing down this question

What I really had was:

```
FOO="bar gum"
$ ssh host spark-submit --verbose --class SomeApp some.jar "$FOO"
```

This should've been:

```
FOO="bar gum"
$ ssh host spark-submit --verbose --class SomeApp some.jar \"$FOO\"
```

Comment: Does escaping the double quotes help?  \"$FOO\"

Comment: Yeah close to it, I was sending it through a ssh command, so the first expansion was caught on that line, DOH!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send a command through the ssh command, any double quotes are interpreted by your local, current shell.

Say you have a simple script, print-first-arg.sh on the remote:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

Then

```
$ ssh host print-first-arg.sh "hello world"
```

Results in

```
$ host print-first-arg.sh hello world
hello
```

On the remote.

Use:

```
$ ssh host echo \"hello world\"
```

and it results in:

```
$ ssh host print-first-arg.sh "hello world"
hello world
```

On the remote